# If I created a SE site for my college, would my college have to host the communication data or would Stack Overflow host it?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

This is really a hypothetical question for my class.

We are designing a system that would be kind of a Stack Overflow-like site for students to talk about academic and career advice. We were thinking instead of creating a discussion board type system from scratch we would use some other software to create it, like Stack Overflow. If we did, would our system hold the communication data? Like the data regarding the posts and the comments and all of that. Or would Stack Overflow control that data?

Would the answer be the same for other discussion board systems?

Comment: I assume you are talking about the Enterprise version, right?
 https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise

Comment: Questions about how to implement your own Stack Exchange-like software are off-topic on meta.stackexchange.com.  meta.stackexchange.com is for discussion and questions about the Stack Exchange sites.  If that's not what you were asking about, I can't tell what you are asking, and I encourage you to edit the question to make it clearer what your question is.

Answer (score 4):

So, there's the public sites, which you can propose on https://area51.stackexchange.com/, but:

- The site would be accessible to everybody, and
- That proposal almost certainly wouldn't fly, for a thousand reasons.

In that case it's run by SE and content posted to it is covered by the usual [TOS](https://stackexchange.com/legal).

Then there's the [Enterprise version](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise), which I don't have first-hand experience with but I think it's safe to assume that:

- It isn't free, but
- It gives you a private instance of the site which you can either host on your own servers or in one of their data centers.
- I'd assume all content you create on your Enterprise instance is specifically owned by you and not by SE.

It sounds like you want to look into the Enterprise version. There is contact info on that page, and the SE team can work with you and give you more concrete information about it.

As for where the data is stored for other systems there is no general answer. Some systems you host on your own servers. Some provide centralized "cloud"-based services. Some, like SE Enterprise, give you an option between the two. You'll just have to check the details on the web sites of the various platforms you find in your research.